# Joining two tables, but only need top row from foreign table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables:

table: `series`:

```
'id', 'series','thumbnail'
```

table: `videos`:

```
'name','ref','sID'
```

sID is a the foreign key for `id` in table `series`.  I want the top 5 rows from table `series`, with the first `ref` for each from `videos`.

However, with my SQL:

```
SELECT  `series` ,  `thumbnail` ,  `ref` 
FROM  `series` 
LEFT JOIN  `videos` ON  `videos`.`sID` =  `series`.`id` 
ORDER BY  `series`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 5
```

I end up with the first top row from `series`, but duplicated 5 times, with the different refs:

```
Youve Already Got It, image.jpg, fe4
Youve Already Got It, image.jpg, 79c57
Youve Already Got It, image.jpg, bd2
Youve Already Got It, image.jpg, ff15c
Youve Already Got It, image.jpg, 2ce
```

Comment: What is the "first ref"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that :

```
SELECT 
`series`, 
`thumbnail`,
(SELECT `ref` FROM `videos` AS `v` WHERE `v`.`sID` = `s`.`id` LIMIT 0,1) AS `ref`
FROM `series` AS `s`
ORDER BY `series`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 0,5
```

Comment: Had to modify the ORDER BY to `s`.`id`, but it works.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know what you're doing with indexes ;)

```
SELECT *, (SELECT ref FROM videos WHERE sID = id LIMIT 1) as first_ref
FROM series
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this also

```
SELECT  `series` ,  `thumbnail` ,  `ref` 
FROM  `series` 
INNER JOIN  `videos` ON  `videos`.`sID` =  `series`.`id` 
GROUP BY  `series`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 5
```